# How to restore android after reset

Tags: android, restore, recovery

I accidently factory reset my android phone..how can I keep my data? All of the options are in Chinese. I have three Google accounts and do not know my passwords. My phone is also encrypted.Please help as I very much need to keep my data.

Still don't have an answer

Comment: this is isn't related to programming. try meta exchange. plenty of online tutorial or articles on such topics. I would suggest resting your passwords and try to log in. you may be able to restore data if you have backup enabled.